# Not all objects inherit from Object instance?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, super

I remember in ES5, it was said that all objects inherit from Object.  (formally, I think it is "inherit from `Object.prototype`")

But in ES6, if I have the following code:

```js
class Dog {
  constructor() {
    super();    // will cause an error
  }
  
}

const woofie = new Dog();
```

In order to use `super()`, it has to `extends Object`:

```js
class Dog extends Object {
  constructor() {
    super();   // this can run
  }
  
}

const woofie = new Dog();
```

Is there a formal rule that objects do not have to inherit from `Object` prototype any more, and it has be the "bottom" base class?

I guess another way to say it is, not all classes have to inherit from Object any more?

Comment: [Try `woofie instanceof Object` when the class doesn't extend Object](https://jsbin.com/sacunirefi/edit?js,console).

Comment: I think that's a `true` -- and extends or not, it is still `true`... interesting, I usually directly use `console.log(woofie.__prototype__)` and this one is `undefined`

Comment: 1. There is no `__prototype__` property, there is `__proto__` 2. Don't use `__proto__`, either. `Object.getPrototypeOf` is the correct way to get some object's prototype.

Comment: that's right... it is `__proto__`, not `__prototype__`... so `console.log(Dog.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype);` gives `true`... so it still inherits from `Object`... so how come cannot call `super()`?

Comment: AFAIK only creating an object using `Object.create(null)` will it not inherit from Object

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, really. You cannot call `super()` without having `extends`. However you don't *have* to call `super()` at all. That's only if you want to invoke the super constructor and it'd be very annoying if *all* objects ever needed that line. It's just noise. All objects inherit from the Object prototype *except* the ones that explicitly don't, e.g., `Object.create(null)` which was also available in ES5. There is basically nothing new here. The class syntax has no bearing on that, it abstracts away the whole prototype thing to make it easier.

Comment: That's specific to `super()`. You can only call `super()` if the class explicitly extends another one.

Comment: I just wanted to follow the rule of "always call super"... so I guess in ES6, it is "always call super, unless if it is just inheriting from Object, in which case, it is useless and ES6 doesn't even allow you to do that"?

Comment: You *have to* call `super()` if the class extends another class **and** you are accessing `this` inside the constructor. That's because the parent class needs to create the object first (and make it available as `this`) before anything else happens. That is to make sure that "exotic" objects (think Arrays) are properly created.

Comment: Btw, `class Foo {}` and `class Foo extends Object {}` are not quite the same. In the second case, `foo` also inherits all methods of `Object` itself (e.g. `keys`, `values`, etc). The instances should be pretty indistinguishable though.

Comment: 'Always call super...if the class is derived". Or in technical terms, has [[constructorKind]] property set to 'derived'. Those kind of classes have peculiar behaviour with 'new' operator. They are mavericks of 'class' world. While normal classes, 'create an empty object, assign it to 'this'', these derived classes expect the constructor from the parent class to do it for them. Such bastards, they are already freeloading on parent methods, the least they could do is creating objects on their own.

Comment: @deeper-understanding "always call super" is "always call super *from a child constructor*". `class Dog {}` is not a *child* of `Object` as Felix Kling points out.

Comment: so I guess JS just makes it really technical? In think in some other language, they may just say, "always call super, but if it doesn't exist, then it is ignored", and so we just always call super and not worry about anything? (or just let everything inherits from Object... like Ruby although I need to double check)

Comment: "*so I guess JS just makes it really technical*" much simpler, really. No need to add excessive verbosity and boilerplate code. It's not conductive to writing useful code. Sprinkling useless calls all over the code just because they'd be ignored doesn't really make for a better codebase.

Comment: if I can choose between least amount of surprise vs can save some line of code, I'd prefer least amount of surprises... but that's a personal choice

Comment: depends on what you expect. if you come from a prototypical inheritance language, then none of this is a surprise